# PlayonLInux+IE8 from one computer to other

Tags: playonlinux

I have installed Internet Explorer 8 using PlayonLinux. Now I want to somehow copy these two programs to other computers. What should I do. The other computers don't have access to internet.

Answer (score 0):

As for PlayOnLinux, you may encounter some problems installing it on a system without internet connection. When you lookup POL's dependencies, you'll get:

```
Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), wine | wine-unstable,
         unzip, wget, xterm | x-terminal-emulator, python-wxgtk2.8,
         imagemagick, cabextract, mesa-utils, gettext-base, binutils,
         gnupg, icoutils, x11-utils, curl, netcat, bzip2, p7zip-full
```

Some of these packages will already be installed, others won't. And all of the not-yet-installed packages have dependencies themselves. Without a internet connection, you'd have to satisfy all these dependencies manually.

Luckily, there are programs and some workarounds to help you. Quite a few are listed as answers to [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). Choose what you like the best ;)

---

As for IE, PlayOnLinux stores it's config and virtual disks in `~/.PlayOnLinux`.

Simply put the whole directory on an USB (You may have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files), and paste it in your users home folder on the target machine.

Then start POL, go to *Configure*, select the virtual drive containing IE, remove the shortcut to IE, then select *General*, *Make a new shortcut*, select *iexplore.exe*, and finish to recreate the shortcut, creating a system launcher with adapted paths.